# Query based on rails hash which is stored as text in postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a table in postgres with a text column. This column is populated with rails with a hash object. This is how the column value looks like:

```
---
:key1:
- value1
- value2
- value3
:key2:
- value4
:key3:
- value5
- value6
```

I need to be able to query the table based on one of the hash value. I have tried converting it into json/jsonb objects but getting this error:

```
[22P02] ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json Detail: Token "-" is invalid.
```

If I load the objects back to Rails, it is fine the field is a hash. However loading all objects in the memory to query based on a field is not practical.
Is there a way to convert this field to json or to a format that makes it easy to query?
This is how the field looks like in Rails:

```
{
  :key1 => [
    "value1",
    "value2",
    "value3"
  ],
  :key2 => [
    "value4"
  ],
  :key3 => [
    "value5",
    "value6"
  ]
}
```

Comment: That's YAML which suggests that you're using `serialize`. How feasible is it to change the column's type to `jsonb`? That would mean something like adding a new `jsonb` column, unpacking each column in Ruby to get a Hash and then sending that Hash back to the database, dropping the original `text` column, and renaming the new `jsonb` column. If you can do that then you could use sane queries, otherwise you have to try to query inside the YAML and that's going to be a mess that will eventually fall apart.

Comment: And while your at it consider if you really want to use JSONB in the first place. If the data has any sort of structure to it use a table instead which is MUCH easier to query properly and will give your data some sort of integrity.

Comment: If you really really had to do this you can [create functions in postgres](http://www.copiousfreetime.org/articles/2009/01/10/writing-sql-functions-in-ruby.html) using any number of languages including Ruby. So in this case you can require psych and use it to parse the YAML and return JSON. But it seems like a huge effort to rectify a bad design decision.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks I changed the column type to jsonb and it works.